# C: assignment to char... expects cast?

Tags: c, casting, command-line-arguments

Using

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    double number1, number2;
    char operator;

    number1 =atof (argv[0]);
    operator =argv[1];        // line 29
    number2 =atof (argv[2]);
```

Compiler complains saying

> 29 warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
>   [enabled by default]

Comment: Since nobody said it yet: `argv[0]` is the name of the executable usually [could be other things, you can call a member of the `exec` family passing whatever for `argv[0]`], the command line arguments you want start at `argv[1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

argv[1] is a pointer to char, you can't assign it to a char. either transform operator to char * or try operator = *(argv[1]);

Answer (score 2):

```
operator =argv[1];        // line 29
```

Here, `argv[1]` is of type `char*`. But `operator` is type `char`. That's the reason for error.

If you want to get only the operator which a single character you pass from command line then:

```
operator=argv[1][0];
```

will do.

Note that it's better to use `strto*` for conversion as `ato*` functions don't detect errors.

Comment: @Duncan It's the first character in `argv[1]`. For example, if you pass `+` in the commandline as `argv[1]` then it would be `"+"`. So when you do `argv[1][0]`, it's the first character in `argv[1]` which is `+` here.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `operator` is of type `char` while `argv[1]` is of type `char *`.

One is a single character, the other is a pointer to characters (i.e. a string).

PS. Even if it works when you only use pure C, you should refrain from using C++ keywords (like `operator`) as it will make it harder to port to C++.